# Substituting values

Tags: replacement

I have a little program that should find values that Solve a system of polynomic equations and then substitute those values function. It solves the system but then, the substitution doesn't happen. I can't see what I'm doing wrong

```
T = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}};
techniques = Dimensions[T][[1]];
factors = Dimensions[T][[2]];
αVec = ConstantArray[1/2, techniques];
λVec = Array[λ, techniques];
γVec = Array[γ, factors];
onesVec = ConstantArray[1, techniques];
FactorNeeds = Transpose[T].λVec^(1/αVec)
Quiet[Solve::ztest1];

varVec = Flatten[{λVec, Subscript[δ, 1]}];
temp = Table[FactorNeeds /.
Flatten[
 Solve[D[FactorNeeds[[j]] - 
     Subscript[δ, 
      1] (onesVec.λVec - 1), {varVec}] == 
   ConstantArray[0, Length[varVec]], varVec, Reals]], {j, 1, 
factors}];
minmax = Table[temp[[j, 2]]/temp[[j, 1]], {j, 1, factors}];
minKL = Min[minmax];
maxKL = Max[minmax];

i = Rationalize[minKL + .3 (maxKL - minKL)];

varVec = Flatten[{λVec, {Subscript[δ, 1], 
 Subscript[δ, 2]}}];
zerosVec = ConstantArray[0, Length[varVec]];
temp = N[Flatten[
Solve[{D[(FactorNeeds[[1]] - 
     Subscript[δ, 1] (λVec.onesVec - 1) + 
     Subscript[δ, 
      2] (FactorNeeds[[2]] - i*FactorNeeds[[1]])), {varVec}] == 
  ConstantArray[0, Length[varVec]], varVec >= zerosVec}, varVec, 
Reals]]]
kVec = FactorNeeds /. temp
```

The output I get is `{λ[1.] -> 0.333166, λ[2.] -> 0.32428, λ[3.] ->
   0.342554, Subscript[δ, 1] -> 1.30963, 
 Subscript[δ, 2] -> 0.371542}`, which is the solution to the second `Solve` and `{2 λ[1]^2 + 3 λ[2]^2 + λ[3]^2, 
 3 λ[1]^2 + 2 λ[2]^2 + 4 λ[3]^2}`, which is just the definition of FactorNeeds. I was asuming that my last line of code would replace the values `λ[j]` in `FactorNeeds` by those obtained in the `Solve`. Can the fact that those are listed as `λ[j.]` rather than `λ[j]` have anything to do with it?

Comment: Thanks, @Kuba. How do I use greek letters within the code? I knew my post looked horrible, but I don't know how to do what you did.

Comment: You can use the site http://steampiano.net/msc/

Comment: Thanks, @Coolwater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `N` you need to add the `NHoldAll` attribute to `λ`:

```
SetAttributes[λ, NHoldAll]
temp = N[...];
kVec = FactorNeeds /. temp
{0.65481527, 1.0126864}
```

Otherwise your variables are modified by `N`, e.g. `λ[2]` becomes `λ[2.]` which prevents `ReplaceAll` from matching the variables in `FactorNeeds`.